Azure/Entra AD with Clerk - How to get the AD details
I'm building a Nextjs app with Clerk and use Azure AD of my organization with prisma and postgres as db, I want to get the details of the users in my organization when they sign up. I've used Clerk for Authentication. How can I get the details that is there in Azure AD when the user signs in?
SignInPage
"use client";
import { SignIn, useUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function SignInPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const user = useUser();
  const isSignedIn = user.isSignedIn;

  if (isSignedIn) {
    router.replace("/onboard");
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <main className="flex h-screen w-full items-center justify-center bg-gray-100 flex-col">
     
      <div className="  p-8 px-24 justify-center items-center flex flex-col">
        <SignIn
          routing="hash"
          appearance={{
            elements: {
              footerAction: {
                display: "none",
              },
            },
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

onboard page
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma";
import { auth, currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export default async function Onboard() {
  const userDetails = await currentUser();
  const user = auth();
  if (!userDetails) {
    return redirect("/"); // Redirect to the homepage directly from the server
  }

  async function createUser(data: {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    externalId: string;
  }) {
    console.log(data);  
    await prisma.user.upsert({
      where: { externalId: userDetails?.id },
      create: { ...data },
      update: { ...data },
    });
  }

  await createUser({
    name: userDetails.fullName as string,
    email: userDetails.primaryEmailAddress?.emailAddress as string,
    externalId: userDetails.id,
  });

  return redirect("/Dashboard");
}

I tried NextAuth but it is very confusing, so decided to switch to clerk and how to do Azure/Entra AD based authentication on this.
